# How to call a javascript function within pug element

Tags: javascript, pug

```
each customer, i in customers        
    tr
        td #{timeConverter(customer.joiningDate)} 


    function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){
        var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
        var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        var year = a.getFullYear();
        var month = months[a.getMonth()];
        var date = a.getDate();
        var hour = a.getHours();
        var min = a.getMinutes();
        var sec = a.getSeconds();
        var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
        return time;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
each customer, i in customers        
    tr
        script.
          var x;
          x=timeConverter(customer.joiningDate);
        td #{x}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I created a route for the function, initialised a global variable and used it in the front end.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Can you check this:

Add this as **first line**:

```
- var timeConverter = function (UNIX_timestamp){ var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];var year = a.getFullYear();var month = months[a.getMonth()];var date = a.getDate();var hour = a.getHours();var min = a.getMinutes();var sec = a.getSeconds();var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;return time;}
```

Add your PUG code below this line

> doctype html
>   html
>     head
>       title
>         My prog PUG
>     body
>       each customer, i in [{joiningDate: new Date()}]
>        tr
>         td #{timeConverter(customer.joiningDate)}

and run :)

try https://pughtml.com/